# PayPal Integration Login Failed Error?

Tags: android, authentication, paypal

[image]

This is my main activity class :

```
 package your.in.paypal;

 import java.math.BigDecimal;
 import android.app.Activity;
 import android.content.Intent;
 import android.os.Bundle;
 import android.util.Log;
 import android.view.View;
 import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
 import android.view.ViewGroup;
 import android.view.ViewGroup.LayoutParams;
 import android.widget.LinearLayout;

 import com.paypal.android.MEP.CheckoutButton;
 import com.paypal.android.MEP.PayPal;
 import com.paypal.android.MEP.PayPalActivity;
 import com.paypal.android.MEP.PayPalPayment;

 public class SimplePayPalIntegration extends Activity implements OnClickListener {
 private ViewGroup content;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    invokeSimplePayment();
}

private void invokeSimplePayment(){

    try{


        PayPal pp = PayPal.getInstance();

        if(pp==null)

        pp = PayPal.initWithAppID(this, "APP-80W284485P519543T", PayPal.ENV_SANDBOX);

        LinearLayout layoutSimplePayment = new LinearLayout(this);

        layoutSimplePayment.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));

        layoutSimplePayment.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);

        CheckoutButton launchSimplePayment = pp.getCheckoutButton(this, PayPal.BUTTON_194x37, CheckoutButton.TEXT_PAY);

        launchSimplePayment.setOnClickListener(this);

        layoutSimplePayment.addView(launchSimplePayment);

        setContentView(layoutSimplePayment);


    }catch(Exception e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

    @Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
         switch(resultCode) {

          case Activity.RESULT_OK:

              Log.d("", "RESULT_OK");
              break;

           case Activity.RESULT_CANCELED:
               Log.d("", "RESULT_CANCELED");
               break;

           case PayPalActivity.RESULT_FAILURE:
               Log.d("", "RESULT_FAILURE");
               break;
      }
}

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {

        PayPalPayment payment = new PayPalPayment();

        payment.setSubtotal(new BigDecimal("8.25"));

        payment.setCurrencyType("USD");

        payment.setRecipient("mymail@gmail.com");

        payment.setPaymentType(PayPal.PAYMENT_TYPE_GOODS);

        Intent checkoutIntent = PayPal.getInstance().checkout(payment, this);

        startActivityForResult(checkoutIntent, 1);

        Log.d("", "clicked");

    }
}
```

And this is my `AndroidManifest.xml` :

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
 package="your.in.paypal"
 android:versionCode="1"
 android:versionName="1.0" >

<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="8" />

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>


<application
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name" >
    <activity
        android:name=".SimplePayPalIntegration"

     android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
      <activity android:name="com.paypal.android.MEP.PayPalActivity" 
                android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Translucent.NoTitleBar"
                android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation"/>
</application>
```

And I have already added The `PayPal_MPL.jar` to the project. When I run the project I successfully go to paypal button and when I click on the button I get login page but when I enter the sandbox login id and password I get the error `Login failed. Please try again.` why? 
Please tell me what I am doing wrong.

Comment: First, just try to login in website. Check whether its correct or not.

Comment: i successfully logged in the site but in the project it is giving error.

Comment: Is there any mistake in code????

Comment: http://www.happygeek.in/paypal-integration-in-android-app 

Try following the steps here again. Try creating a new account and logging information again :)

Comment: use mpl.jar file means try another mpl.jar file some time its not working

Comment: payment.setSubtotal(new BigDecimal(8.25)); 
change this

Comment: i too faced same problem, then i came to know that i gave sandbox login email_id and password. this is my mistake, after giving testing account email_id and password, it worked.

Comment: see if this solves your problem https://www.x.com/developers/paypal/forums/mobile/login-fails-mobile-app

Answer (score 3):

The problem is that you are trying to do real payments in Sandbox mode. PayPal will only allow you to make actual payments once you are on their live servers (after they have had a chance to review and approve your app). Sign up at X.com and submit your app there when you are ready to try payments. Alternatively you can setup sandbox accounts through the paypal website.

Comment: @Jason- Thanks, i'll try which you suggested me .

Answer (score 0):

You need to visit https://www.sandbox.paypal.com and create an account so that you can use it in Sandbox mode. I was getting exactly the same message, "Login failed. Please try again." After registering my Sandbox account, I could test successfully and it is great that you do not have to worry about spending money from your real account.